# How to determine if C# executable is being run from zip file?

Tags: c#, .net-core, unzip

I'm trying to ensure that users of my C# .NET Core program always unzip it before running, however, I can't seem to find a good solution for this.

I tried using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` and checking if it contained `Temp` but it did not work as intended. My understanding is that when running an executable within a zipped file, Windows will automatically unzip (?) to a temp directory and then proceed.

Any ideas on how to go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: What does look like the `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` value?

Comment: "but it did not work as intended" - can you please be more specific?

Comment: "I'm trying to ensure that users of my C# .NET Core program always unzip it before running" **why**? This seems like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be that you put another file beside the exe file inside the zip file and make the exe find for this file in the same location of the exe.

When an exe is executed from inside a zip, the unzip program will unzip the exe but not the other file and checking for this file you can test whether just the exe was unzziped or if the whole files where unzipped and the guess it was installed.

(Anyway, I agree with Ian Kemp, as it seems to be an XY problem)..

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two checks that will work in *many* cases. Obviously, these checks are not bullet-proof.

1. Most `.zip` viewers will extract the clicked `.exe` in a temporary folder.
2. Windows Explorer zip folder view runs the `.exe` from a temporary folder **and** sets the `ReadOnly` attribute.

### Sample app

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace SimpleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private static bool IsLikelyRunFromZipFolder()
        {
            var path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
            return fileInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
        }

        private static bool IsRunFromTempFolder()
        {
            var path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
            var temp = Path.GetTempPath();
            return path.IndexOf(temp, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var isTemp = IsRunFromTempFolder();
            var isZip = IsLikelyRunFromZipFolder();
            
            Console.WriteLine($"Run from TEMP folder? {isTemp}");
            Console.WriteLine($"LIKELY run from Windows Explorer ZIP folder? {isZip}");
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I disagree with the sceptics in this thread. Running an `exe` from a "zip folder" in Windows Explorer is indeed a common source of error. By showing a warning, inexperienced users could get some immediate advice.